# How can I extract text from an uploaded file to populate a Django model field?

Tags: python, django, file

I'm writing a Django application which will require a Script object which has access both to a file containing the script and the fulltext of the script.  The script file is an xls file, and I have no problems in extracting the data from it or writing data to it programmatically (xlrd and friends are great!), and I'm storing it in a models.FileField.  I would like to store the fulltext in a models.TextField, but my problem is that I don't know how to put the workflow together correctly so that the fulltext and the stored file mirror each other.

Workflows I want:

Script object created -> file uploaded to file field -> text extracted from file saved to fulltext field

and

Script fulltext edited -> text written back to file in file field -> script saved

and

Script file replaced with new file -> text extracted from file saved to fulltext field

I have been playing around with the signals framework (presave and postsave), but I don't know how to make it, er, save the changes that I am hoping for, since that would require calling save->generating an infinite loop.  Also, presave seems to be invoked before the file is uploaded (using a form), which makes my server puke at me.

Any ideas?

Comment: It turns out that I was overengineering this problem.  The signal I was actually looking for was post_init, and the function that I wrote is literally just

@receiver(post_save, sender=Script)def retrieve_fulltext(sender, **kwargs):
script = kwargs['instance']
s = open(script.script.path)
text = s.read()
if script.fulltext == text:
  return
else:
  script.fulltext = text
  script.save()

Which still, yes, requires a bit more to make it work with changes in fulltext triggering a write to the file.

Sorry, SO, for asking a silly question.  I hope this answer is at least useful to someone else.

Comment: You should do some validation on the file you are uploading to make sure the content is safe, particularly if you are saving that content to another model field!

Comment: If you found the answer yourself, go ahead and post it as an answer to your own question. It's not bad form, and it helps future searchers who may have the same question.

Comment: Also, consider overriding save instead of using signals. It's almost always the cleaner answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I was overengineering this problem. The signal I was actually looking for was post_init, and the function that I wrote is literally just

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Script)
def retrieve_fulltext(sender, **kwargs):
    script = kwargs['instance']
    s = open(script.script.path)
    text = s.read()

    if script.fulltext == text:
        return else: script.fulltext = text
        script.save()
```

Which still, yes, requires a bit more to make it work with changes in fulltext triggering a write to the file. Sorry, SO, for asking a silly question. I hope this answer is at least useful to someone else.